# Separate check box value to separate text area

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var itemsAdded = Array();

function moveNumbers(text) { 
var i = itemsAdded.indexOf(text)
if ( i >= 0) { 
itemsAdded.splice(i,1);
} else {
itemsAdded.push(text);
}
document.getElementById("result1").value=itemsAdded.join(" ");

if ( i >= 0) {  

} else{
itemsAdded.push(text);
}
document.getElementById("result2").value=itemsAdded.join(" "); 
}

$(function() {
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
console.log(i);
$("body").append("<input type='checkbox' name='add' value='" + i + "' 
  onclick='moveNumbers(this.value)'/> Checkbox" + i + "<br/>");
 }
});

</script>


<table width="95%" height="24" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<th><h2>Selected Image 5x7</h2></th>
<tr>
<td>
<textarea rows="4" cols="70" name="add" id="result1" style="background:#B0D2D7;
width:100%;overflow:auto;resize:none"
readonly></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><tr>
<th><h2>Selected Image 6x8</h2></th>
<tr>
<td>
<textarea rows="4" cols="70" name="add" id="result2" style="background:#B0D2D7;
width:100%;overflow:auto;resize:none"
readonly></textarea>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Hi all, new at this so I apologize if it's rather messy.

I have this working but when I check the boxes the value's do appear in the text areas, but text it self is all over the place. Also need the check boxes, when unchecked to remove the text from the text area. Any ideas would be great! Hopes this makes sense...

Cheers.

Comment: It looks to me like your html is not formatted correctly at all.  Unclosed tags, missing markup, no body element no head element.  look into basic html...

Comment: not interested in the html bit right now, only the java

Comment: java is not javascript, and javascript needs valid html to work usually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/KCmbm/2/

NOTE: if you are not going to use special tags like [b]: use commented code(but it will replace all occurences of supplied text);

Javscript

```
var itemsAdded = Array();

function moveNumbers(text) {
    console.log(text);
    var addedText = '[b' + text + ']' + text + '[/b]';
    $('#result1').val($('#result1').val() + addedText);
    //$('#result1').val($('#result1').val() + text);

    console.log(addedText);
}

function removeText(text){
    //$('#result1').val($('#result1').val().replace(new RegExp(text, 'g'), ''));
    $('#result1').val($('#result1').val().replace('[b' + text + ']' + text + '[/b]', ''));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chkAdd').on('change', function(){
        $(this).prop('checked') ? moveNumbers($(this).val()) : removeText($(this).val());
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks Dart, and others for your time

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have to be so messy as you describe. Besides, I don't know how it is working for you as the structure of html is clearly broken in the current state.

Following is a bit of updated code, which I believe is equivalent to what you are trying to achieve with your snippet. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yzvbL/3/)

**JS:**

```
var itemsAdded = Array();

function moveNumbers() {
    var text = this.value;
    var i = itemsAdded.indexOf(text)
    if (i >= 0) itemsAdded.splice(i, 1);
    else itemsAdded.push(text);
    document.getElementById("result1").value = itemsAdded.join(" ");

    if (i < 0) itemsAdded.push(text);
    document.getElementById("result2").value = itemsAdded.join(" ");
}

$(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    $("<div>Checkbox" + i + "</div>").appendTo(document.body)
        .prepend($("<input type='checkbox' name='add'/>")
        .val(i).click(moveNumbers));
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table width="95%" height="24" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <th>
         <h2>Selected Image 5x7</h2>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <textarea rows="4" cols="70" name="add" id="result1" readonly></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
         <h2>Selected Image 6x8</h2>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <textarea rows="4" cols="70" name="add" id="result2" readonly></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
textarea {
    background:#B0D2D7;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    resize:none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not attaching the on click event correctly. They don't even get fired. See this example below. Once the checkboxes are added, attach the click event. You can get the value of the element from `this` as shown below.  [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T54EE/)

```
var itemsAdded = Array();

function moveNumbers() {
    var i = itemsAdded.indexOf(this.value)
    if (i >= 0) {
        itemsAdded.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
        itemsAdded.push(this.value);
    }
    document.getElementById("result1").value = itemsAdded.join(" ");

    if (i < 0) {
        itemsAdded.push(this.value);
    }
    document.getElementById("result2").value = itemsAdded.join(" ");
}

$(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        $("body").append("<input type='checkbox' name='add' value='" + i + "'/> Checkbox" + i + "<br/>");
    }

    $("input:checkbox").click(moveNumbers);
});
```